# найти пост по его id и номеру группы VK API

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть пост и номер группы в VK, необходимо с помощью VK API найти пост.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать https://vk.com/dev/wall.getById
В параметре posts передавать строку вида -1_123 для сообщества с id 1, а поста с id 123.

Важно, что для группы owner_id должен быть отрицательным, так что строка обязательно должна начинаться с минуса.